# How to pass data between two viewcontrollers in iwatch?

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

I am working on a app which sends notification to iwatch.I want to show notification msg on next viewcontroller, how to pass data from notification viewcontroller to next viewcontroller in page based navigation?

Comment: please answer if anybody have any idea about this, Thanks in advanced

Comment: does anybody else has any information regarding this? please refer following conversation also.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm having the exact same problem. I'm not pushing controllers programatically, so my contextForSegue is not being called. Page Controller with 2 views. How can I pass data through!?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceController):

> When pushing a new interface controller, it is recommended that you
>   pass a context object to the pushControllerWithName:context: method. A
>   context object is your only way to communicate information to the new
>   interface controller about what it should display. A context object
>   can be an existing data object, or it can be a dictionary that you
>   create dynamically and fill with relevant information.
>
> If you prefer to use segues to initiate hierarchical navigation
>   between interface controllers, WatchKit calls the
>   contextForSegueWithIdentifier:inTable:rowIndex: or
>   contextForSegueWithIdentifier: method based on whether the source of
>   the segue was a table row or a button. Use those methods to provide
>   the context object needed to initialize the new interface controller.

Comment: thanks jack but my contextsForSegueWithIdentifier: method is not getting called I am using paging navigation in storyboard.

Comment: even my handleActionWithIdentifier method for remote notification is not getting called in notificationcontroller,is I am missing anything? I am using Dynamic NotificationController.

Comment: Are you sure you set the class of the Storyboard interface to your custom class?

Comment: yes Dynamic notification interface is set to default Notification Controller and others are set to custom class.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to pass data than simply use this ...**

```
NSString *a = @"a";
NSString *b = @"b";

[self pushControllerWithName:@"DetailViewController" context:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"name",b,@"id", nil]];
```

**and goto the push view and log it's context..**

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    NSLog(@"context %@",context);
}
```

in context see the dictionary formate where you can set before pushing the view.

Answer (score 0):

I found [the answer here](http://www.codedisqus.com/CzVqVgkXeW/how-to-pass-the-array-data-from-one-interface-to-another-in-watchkit-using-pagebased-navigation.html)

Basically you need to reload the controller (or page) you want to pass the context to.

```
// Inside Init or awakeFromContext of "Page1"
// Reload the next controller and pass the context or data you want
[WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"Page2"] contexts:@[someData]];
```